# Modifying VSCode extension configuration does not report ('key' in obj); how?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

Developing a VS Code extension, I'm passing a configuration object with `{around:1}` to a library. The library has the following code (slightly simplified for this question):

```js
if (!('before' in opts))  opts.before  = ('around' in opts) ? opts.around : 0;
if (!('before1' in opts)) opts.before1 = ('before' in opts) ? opts.before : 0;
```

After this code runs, `opts.before === 1`, and `opts.before1 === 0`. How is this possible? What's going on?

The configuration object comes from:

```js
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(extName).get(settingName)[name];
```

...where `name` is something like `"docs"` and the value of the setting is:

```
{
   "docs": {"wrap":true, "around":1, "indent":"  "},
   // other values here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever VS Code does to merge configuration settings together returns not a plain object, but some sort of Proxy object. For some reason setting a property on this object does not result in the object having that property itself.

The workaround is to copy the configuration values into a plain object before passing them to the library:

```js
   let opts = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(extName).get(settingName)[name];
   opts = Object.assign({}, opts);
```